# How to show submenu in siebar for menu showing inloop in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working in Ionic App and I want to show the submenu in the sidebar. I am fetching the menus using the `*ngFor` but the problem is that I am not able to show the submenu.

This is my **app.html**:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="left" type="overlay">
    <ion-content class="mymenu22">
     <ion-grid class="formenu11">
      <h1 class="mymenuh11">OTHERS</h1>
     </ion-grid>
     <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p1 of pages1" (click)="openPage(p1)" class="menu2">
        <ion-icon name="{{p1.name1}}"></ion-icon> {{p1.title1}}
      </button>
     </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

In this, I am showing the menus in the sidebar and I want to show the submenu for the first menu.

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
pages1: Array<{title1: string, component: any, name1: string}>;
this.pages1 = [
  { title1: 'Manage Account', component: ManageaccountPage, name1: 'settings' },
  { title1: 'About Us', component: AboutPage, name1: 'people' },
  { title1: 'Gallery', component: GalleryPage, name1: 'images' },
  { title1: 'Contact Us', component: ContactPage, name1: 'contacts' },
];
```

For the Manage Account, I want to show the submenu.

[image]

For the Manage Account, I want to show the submenu but I am not getting any code for this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-orqvdd?file=pages%2Fabout%2Fabout.html  Is this ok?

Answer (score 1):

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      public appPages = [
        { title: 'Home', url: 'home', icon: 'home' },
        { title: 'About', url: '/about', icon: 'people' },
        { title: 'Contact', url: '/contact', icon: 'call' },
        { title: 'Gallery', url: '/gallery', icon: 'images' },
        { title: 'Setting', url: '/setting', icon: 'settings',
     children: [
            { title: 'sub-menu1', url: '/sub-menu1', icon: 'person' },
            { title: 'sub-menu2', url: '/sub-menu2', icon: 'person' },
            { title: 'sub-menu3', url: '/sub-menu3', icon: 'pulse' }
          ] }
      ];
      constructor() {}
    }


==app.component.html==

<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane >
    <ion-menu menuId="custom">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar >
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
       <div *ngFor="let p of appPages">
        <ion-menu-toggle *ngIf="p.url">
          <ion-item (click)="sidemenuClick(p)" [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]"  [routerLinkActive]="['active-menu']">
            <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label class="menu-name">
              {{p.title}}
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-item button *ngIf="p.children?.length > 0" (click)="p.open = !p.open"
          [class.active-parent]="p.open" detail="false">
          <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>          
          <ion-label class="menu-name">
            {{p.title}}
          </ion-label>
          <ion-icon  slot="end" name="arrow-dropdown" *ngIf="p.open"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon  slot="end" name="arrow-dropright" *ngIf="!p.open"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-list *ngIf="p.open">
          <ion-menu-toggle>
            <ion-item  style="padding-left: 20px;" *ngFor = "let sub of p.children" (click)="sidemenuClick(p)" [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[sub.url]"  [routerLinkActive]="['active-menu']">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="sub.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label class="menu-name">
                {{sub.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
       </div>
      </ion-content>
      <ion-footer class="bar-stable" (click)="logout()">
        <ion-menu-toggle>
          <ion-item class="sign-out">
            <ion-icon class="app-color logo" slot="end" name="log-out"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label class="app-color name">Sign Out</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
      </ion-footer>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.